# The opposite of requiring a critical mass, being able to bootstrap from ground?

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives

I am looking for an adjective for my system. I try to define the property that the system can bootstrap without requiring a critical mass of adoption. Meaning it can start functioning from zero and get adopted smoothly.

The idea is the opposite of requiring a tipping point. However, I cannot put my finger on it. It is also relevant to the notion of "first-movers advantage", but then again, not exactly what I am looking for.

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: The opposite of a system that requires critical mass to function might be one that is **self perpetuating**.

Comment: or self-sustaining.  Or something that creates a virtuous circle (the opposite of a vicious circle).

Comment: Perhaps not ideal choices: when *critical mass* is reached,  a process *becomes* self-perpetuating/self-sustaining.

Comment: Your question requires an example sentence. Without context, we are guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a system is **self-starting**

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-starting)
>
> capable of starting by oneself or itself
>
> Or **self-initiating**
>
> caused or facilitated to begin by oneself : initiated by oneself

The idea of critical mass is actually a little confusing in this question. If there is a critical mass, it is of something (fissile nuclear material, people exchanging ideas, reactive chemical constituents, etc) present in sufficient quantity to start a process (nuclear power generation or nuclear explosion, generation of new ideas, chemical reaction etc). The process is often described as a chain reaction.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chain%20reaction)
>
> chain reaction:
>
> a number of events triggered by the same initial event

The chain reaction process started by a critical mass is therefore a only a special case of a self-starting process.

*Self-starting* does not relate to what happens *after* starting. The process may finish abruptly as in nuclear explosion; it may continue in a self-perpetuating manner as nuclear power generation or in a forest fire; it may proceed in some incremental way, with the addition of new material or ideas.

Continuous generation, explosion, incrementalism and self-perpetuation are therefore all secondary to the starting of the process and do not describe your key need for the gerundial adjective *self-starting*.

Answer (score 1):

**incremental (adoption)**

**incremental** (adj.)

> Of, relating to, being, or occurring in especially small increments
>
> *incremental additions*
>
> *incremental change* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incremental)

---

> **Incremental adoption** approach. Companies are advised to start using Q-Rapids in a small product first in order to understand the
> solution and start to grow a base of tailored connectors and a quality
> model fit for purpose. [Manuel Mazzara et al.; *Software Technology:
> Methods and Tools*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Software_Technology_Methods_and_Tools/mMi0DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=incremental%20adoption%20of%20a%20solution&pg=PA390&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> To design a solution which lays out the foundation for the systematic,
> **incremental adoption** of good ERP RE practice in cross-organizational projects, we applied the following two-stage
> design approach: .... [S. Parthasarathy; *Enterprise Information
> Systems and Implementing IT Infrastructures*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Enterprise_Information_Systems_and_Imple/7rpTVcd5E7UC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=incremental%20adoption%20of%20a%20solution&pg=PA5&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

> ... and major adoption characteristics of the cloud computing adoption
> framework for developing countries, i.e., an **incremental adoption**
> of cloud computing technology components—using available components
> instead of waiting for the availability of the entire solution. [C. K.
> Ayo and V. Mbarika; *Sustainable ICT Adoption and Integration for
> Socio-Economic Development*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sustainable_ICT_Adoption_and_Integration/s3BxDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=incremental%20adoption%20of%20a%20solution&pg=PA195&printsec=frontcover) (2017)

> As stated by one respondent, "We would have been doing **incremental**
> research, not this enabling research which requires **critical mass**.
> [U.S. Congress; *FY 1996 TA/NIST Budget Authorization*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/FY_1996_TA_NIST_Budget_Authorization/FzWDOg7EYqgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22incremental%22%20and%20does%20not%20require%20a%20critical%20mass&pg=PA380&printsec=frontcover)